# setInterval function not always working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

So, I tried to do an animated banner (containing two images- #baner1 and #baner2. When one fades out the second fades in). It works properly most of the times, but sometimes these images change rapidly (like one second after each other, despite the timer is 12000 miliseconds). Any idea what causes it?

My code:

```
setInterval(()=>{
  $('#baner1').fadeOut(2000);
  $('#baner2').fadeIn(2000);
},12000)

setInterval(()=>{
  $('#baner1').fadeIn(2000);
  $('#baner2').fadeOut(2000);
},24000)
```

Also, it's (as far as I know) my only code affecting these images.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Juat be sure that you make this process after document is loaded. Maybe your one image size is bigger than the other and it isnt loaded before this setinterval function works. Can you try to call this function after loading all elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callbacks are overlapped.

They go like `a`, `a+b`, `a`, `a+b`...

The `a+b` is sometimes executed as `b+a` (because two `setInterval`s aren't synchronized perfectly) and I think this is what's causing you trouble.

What you meant to do is `a`, `b`, `a`, `b`...

You can try changing you logic to use a single `setInterval`, and use a variable to know if it's the `a` "turn" or the `b` "turn". Something like this:

```
let nextTurn = 'a';
setInterval(()=>{
    if (nextTurn === 'a') {
        $('#baner1').fadeOut(2000);
        $('#baner2').fadeIn(2000);
        nextTurn = 'b';
    } else {
        $('#baner1').fadeIn(2000);
        $('#baner2').fadeOut(2000);
        nextTurn = 'a';
    }
},12000)
```